# what contributes to the temperature of a vacuum

Tags: temperature

what is the temperature of Vacuum since temperature of a system is related to the average of the molecular kinetic energy and there is no molecule in a vacuum? i know there could be radiations but i want to know how much the contribution is?

Comment: There are no perfect vacuums, either man-made or in nature. So, there are particles (and as pointed out below, photons) in the volume.

Comment: This is not about chemistry...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about physics, not chemistry.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on how the vacuum is defined. If you, for instance, pump all the air out of a steel container, you will have a vacuum in there. Yet, there will be photons constantly radiated off of the walls. This interplay of photons will be in thermal equilibrium with the walls and therefore will have a contribution to the temperature. For instance, if you would place a thermometer inside this container, the material of the thermometer would be hit by the photons of the container wall and therefore the thermometer would give a temperature equal to the temperature of the wall. As a matter of fact, even in the deepest of deep space, there is some radiation to be found which gives a temperature of about 3K. (This radiation is left over from the Big Bang)

Nevertheless, if you make a true vacuum inside some container of which the walls are at 0 K that cannot be penetrated by any kind of radiation or matter, then the temperature therein is 0 K.

Comment: There's no perfect vacuum and nothing has 0 Kelvin

Comment: Well... yes and no. Indeed, the [Casimir effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) would prevent the creation of a true vacuum, yet see [this Science article](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/339/6115/52) for an example of a sub-zero Kelvin temperature. :-)

Comment: Heard about it earlier and well it's not "true" temperature.